# How to set custom shortcut involving only Left or Right Alt?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 22.04, workspaces, customization

I am currently using ubuntu 22.04. I want to set a custom shortcut like

`<LEFT ALT> + Left/Right ----> to shift workspaces <Like a MAC>`

Whereas the `<RIGHT ALT>` must remain with all the functionalities. Also the `<LEFT ALT>` must work like `<RIGHT ALT>` in all other scenarios. Is there a way to set a custom shortcut like that ?

I searched for many solutions online, but I feel that there are no apt answers for the same. Hence reaching you out for the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not think one can differentiate between left and right alt keys in dconf-editor. Apart from that, one can of course set Alt+Left/Right as such to move workspaces.

Comment: But by default, Alt+Left/Right is used for backward and forward in browser. So I want to use that functionality also with the help of right alt

Comment: I hope you find a solution.